# Client not able to connect to FTP server (only filezilla works)

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ftp, vsftpd

I have created a FTP Server on a Amazon-EC2 instance following [this DigitalOcean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-18-04), I can login normally and that's the only part that works remotely using the shell(connecting from server to localhost doesn't give any problem), but any command that i give to FTP client( e.g. `ls` or `put source destination`) doesn't work.
The tutorial sets the server to work in PASSIVE mode, but while looking for solutions online and the people had a problem with mode X, the solution was switching from mode X to mode Y and viceversa.

---

### FTP (verbose mode) gives two different outputs:

- While connection is on ACTIVE mode

```
ftp> dir
500 Illegal PORT command.
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

- When connection is on PASSIVE mode

```
ftp> dir
227 Entering Passive Mode (addr, of, my, server, port1, port2).
ftp: connect: Connection timed out
```

Although the command line FTP client can't perform any operation different from login, Filezilla can.
I guess the solution lies in filezilla status logs:

```
Status: Connecting to addr:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Status: Calculating timezone offset of server...
Status: Timezone offset of server is 0 seconds.
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

---

For your information, using Filezilla is not an option: I just installed it to have a good looking client to perform basic operations and tests, but it turned out to be the only client that could do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem with a server hosted on AWS EC2.

I solved it by disabling listen_ipv6 and adding below attributes in the config and then restart vsftpd

> listen_ipv6=NO 
> listen=YES 
> pasv_enable=YES 
> pasv_address=ec2-external-ip